# Doing what COUNTIF does, but including merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

Yes, i know, merged cells are bad, but i need them for aesthethic reasons!

I have a bunch of cells with a label (a brief text) on them; i want to count how many times each labeled is present in a defined range. Doing this is easy with countif...but the aesthethic impact is awful. If i merge them all the appereance is good, but countif doesn't help anymore because it counts the whole cell as one.

I've been trying to figure out how to do what i want with a vba module, but i'm too bad for that.

This one gives me the number of cells from the first cell that has the string i search for.

```
Function dcounter(r As Range, s As String) As Integer
   dcounter = 0
   If Not r.Find(s) Is Nothing Then dcounter = r.Find(s).MergeArea.Cells.Count
End Function
```

I just need to figure out how to loop this for the whole range. I've been trying to play with For Each with no success. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post an image and/or better explain what is counted and what isn't?

Comment: FYI formatting as “centre across selection” gives the aesthetic of merged cells without any actual merging. In which case, countif works just fine.

Comment: Please show us the formula that does not work on merged cells. BTW, why are merged cells bad?

Comment: Since `COUNTIF` will work on merged cells, it is hard to understand your problem. Please read the HELP topic for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to show that.

Comment: I usually deal with the aesthethics by controlling grid lines and cell colouring. Adjoining cells coloured white will hide grid lines between them where as cells without colour show them. You can hide all grid lines in the sheet and apply borders of the default width and colour of grid lines where you want them.

Comment: =COUNIF(A:A,"??") will return the correct result regardless of how many of the cells in column A are merged with other columns. Bear in mind that the value of a merged range is attributed to its first cell. Therefore the count would be different if executed in column B and some of the cells were merged with column A. In short, your problem isn't well defined as well as probably unnecessary.

Comment: You could remove the merged cells (if merged horizontally) and replace with `Center Across Selection` in the cell formatting/alignment dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Function CountMerged(rng As Range, txt As String)
    Dim col As Collection, n As Long, c
    Set col = FindAll(rng, txt)
    For Each c In col
        n = n + c.MergeArea.Count
    Next c
    CountMerged = n
End Function

Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection

    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Debug.Print rng.Cells.Count

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        Debug.Print f.Address
        rv.Add f
        'Note: FindNext() won't work in a UDF
        Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

**Note** - merging/unmerging will not trigger a recalculation of the UDF, even if you add `Application.Volatile`  It's not clear though from your question whether you're looking for a UDF...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
Function dcounter(r As Range, s As String) As Integer
  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In r
    If c.Value = s Then
      dcounter = dcounter + c.MergeArea.Count
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Reference: [Range.Find method - For Each...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#remarks)